# Increment time in date variable

Tags: java, time

I have a date variable, which contains some data like `May 04 10:00:00 IST 2013`. I need to increment the time of this variable. If the time incremented is more than 24 hours it should increment the date also. How can I do this?

Comment: how you are incrementing the time.Can u show the code

Comment: Show what you have tried and what not working.

Comment: this is as simple as `date.getTime() + 24*60*60*1000l`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just guessing you are using Calendar

```
Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar(); // creates calendar
//You can do arithmetic in this line  
//c.add(Calendar.HOUR,-24) //24 hour subtracting
c.add(Calendar.HOUR,24); // 24 hour adding.. 
c.getTime(); //new date is returned
```

Hope this helps!

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use `GregorianCalendar`.

`GregorianCalendar` class has method `add(int field, int amount)` where field should be `DAY_OF_MONTH`.

Answer (score 3):

Try Something like this

```
 String myTime = "14:10";
 SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
 Date d = df.parse(myTime); 
 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
 cal.setTime(d);
 cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 10);
 String newTime = df.format(cal.getTime());
```

using Apache Commons Lang:

```
Date incrementedDate = DateUtils.addHour(startDate, 1);
```

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/time/DateUtils.html

Answer (score 1):

The following code demonstrates adding 3 hours to the `Date` object

```
    Date d = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(d);
    c.add(Calendar.HOUR, 3);
    d = c.getTime();
```

You can get an instance of `Calendar`, and using the `add` method you can add the hour, or minutes or seconds accordingly. The above code will add `3` to the current hours. Similarly you can add 30 minutes to current minutes by

```
c.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
```

Answer (score 1):

GregorianCalendar is a nice thing, but if you are ok to do some math, you can just do like this: myDate.setTime(myDate.getTime() + incrementInMilliseconds);

Or, if you want to increment seconds:
myDate.setTime(myDate.getTime() + incrementInSeconds*1000);
for minutes, it's going to be incrementInMinutes*60*1000, etc.

It will increment date, month, year, etc automatically.
Hope it helped!
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date dateVariable = cal.getTime();   // This gives current Date
    System.out.println(dateVariable);


    cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, 13);  // Incrementing hour by 13,
    cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 20); // Incrementing minutes by 20, similarly you can increment seconds and milisec
     Date updatedDate = cal.getTime();
     System.out.println(updatedDate);
```

Arithematic on Date can only be performed using Calendar Objects. Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

to keep it simple:

```
Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()); //today
date = new Date(date.getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000); //new date adding a day
System.out.println(date); //printing the date in the standard format
```

date is stored as a long (number of milliseconds since The Epoch), so you can add to it 24h in a day, times 60 minutes in an hour, times 60 seconds in a minute, times 1000 milliseconds in a second. and get the next day.